# How to extract string in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

For example, I have a string as below:

```
<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "Telecommunications law"@en <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/>
```

What is the easiest way to extract the substring:

```
Telecommunication law
```

Please note that the substring contains a space.

Comment: Duplicate of a number of other questions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710138/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-a-string-in-java not the least among them.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Pattern and Matcher :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\".*\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if(m.find()){
   String resultString = m.group();
}
```

In your case, resultString will contain ["Telecommunications law"] and you can trim the double quotes if you don't want to keep them.

Answer (score 1):

`String.split()` the string on `"`, and select the second element in the returned array:

```
String tokens[] = yourString.split("\"");

// tokens[1] will contain Telecommunications law
```

Comment: I want extract substring by using regex.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean "extracting the string" ?

getting the first occurence of the string is by:

```
int index = string.indexOf("Telecommunications law");
```

the most efficient way of getting what is in between the first parenthesis and the second is by:

```
final String test="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label \"Telecommunications law\"@en http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/";
final int firstIndex=test.indexOf('\"');
final int lastIndex=test.indexOf('\"',firstIndex+1);
final String result=test.substring(firstIndex+1,lastIndex);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: @andriod developer from that string i need only Telecommuniation law.

Comment: again , do you want what is in between the parenthesis ? or maybe you just want to check if the specified string exists? either way , i've answered both using the code i've written .

Comment: @andriod develope you wright in 2nd question(want to check if the specified string exists) and want what is between the parenthesis.

Comment: i don't understand . if you mean how to check if the string exists , just check that the integer you get from the first code is non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 String str = "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label \"Telecommunications law\"@en http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" ;

 String temp = str.substring(str.indexOf('\"')+1, str.indexOf('\"',str.indexOf('\"')+1));
 System.out.print(temp);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
String yourString = "<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> \"Telecommunications law\"@en <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/>";
        String tokens[] = yourString.split("\"");

        for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
            if(tokens[i].equals("Telecommunications law")){
                System.out.println(tokens[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```